# Which is best to implement Polls embedded inside SharePoint modern pages? MS Forms OR Yammer

Tags: office-365, yammer, microsoft-forms, yammer-embed

I am working on a new SharePoint online site. And the customer asked to have the ability to add Polls on different places inside the SharePoint site home page.

Now based on my investigations and reading (such as this link https://sharepointmaven.com/5-ways-to-create-a-poll-in-microsoft-365/), i found that we have 2 main options inside Office 365 to build Polls capabilities and embed them inside SharePoint, since SharePoint does not  provide any out of the box Poll capabilities:-

1. Using MS Forms
2. Using Yammer

But not sure which provide better feature and capabilities?

Based on my testing i can list these:-

1. **MS Forms**

*Pros*

- Easy to implement
- We can embed 2 different polls on 2 different sections of the home page

*cons*

- When the user submit his/her feedback >> the user can NOT view the overall results

2. **Yammer**

*Pros*

- Also Easy to implement
- When the user submit his/her feedback >> the user can view the overall results

*cons*

- We can NOT embed 2 different polls on 2 different sections of the home page. as we can only show all the Polls inside the community.. so all the Polls need to be shown under each other inside the home page.

So can anyone advice on this? Yammer Vs MS Forms for embedding Polls inside SharePoint modern pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your needs, I wouldn't say one is necessarily better than the other. However, I did want to give you an option to showing results with Microsoft Forms. To achieve this, add the form to your SharePoint page using the Microsoft Forms web part, then edit the webpart and change the setting from "Collect responses" to "Show form results". This way utilizing 2 webparts you can have one to collect the responses and the other showing the current results.

Below is a screenshot of how this is set up:

[image: MS Forms Results]

The only downside to this that I noticed is the results wont show until you refresh the page.